# "Nominator" or "Numerator"?

Tags: terminology, mathematics

Consider the fraction 3/7.

In Mathematics, "7" in the expression is called "denominator" of the fraction. But in the case of "3", some people call it "nominator", and some call it "numerator". Which one is true and more commonly used?

Comment: A [nominator](http://www.onelook.com/?w=nominator&ls=a) is _one who nominates_.  If we were going to cut a pizza, and someone shouted, "Cut it into twelfths!", then the shouter would be the nominator, for nominating 12 slices.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics%29

Comment: OED says this meaning of "nominator" is "rare".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was taught that "numerator" was the correct form.  I have never heard "nominator" until now.  Google Ngrams seems to agree.

[image]